# Oracle Virtual Box: How to access USB 2.0 device without using extension pack in windows

Tags: virtualbox

Is there any way to access an USB 2.0 device in Oracle virtual box without extension pack installed?

I have USB2.0 device in host machine, can I access that device in Guest machine as USB1.1?

I am able to see the device on virtual box device manager with yellow ( driver not supported) 
How can I access USB 2.0 device in virtulal box as USB1.1

Oracle VM Version: 5.2.4

Comment: I believe you can, although don't expect fast transfer speed. On the guest machine, go to the VBox contextual menu(at the top or bottom of the screen) go to devices an find your usb device a select it, so it will the device to the vm.

Comment: I am able to see the device on virtual box device manager with yellow ( driver not supported)

Comment: If you are using a dock see [this advice](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16338?cversion=0&cnum_hist=6#comment:10) to stop the VM and close virtual box, undock and redock, the driver then reloads properly and you can resume the VM. See also [this advice](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=88316&start=15#p423991) for USB3 settings (although your hardware may require different settings).

Comment: I don’t use dock , I am connecting device to my laptop. I tried reconnecting the device several times

Comment: The documentation says that you need the extension pack to use USB. You might try to install in the VM a driver for the USB adapter of your choice. If you have difficulties locating a driver, let me know the involved Windows version and emulated hardware of the VM.

Comment: For some reasons I cannot install extension pack, Host and guest machine is Windows 10. When I connect USB2 in host machine , I need to access USB device as USB1.1 in guest machine. I don’t want to get as USB2.

Comment: Perhaps you should be asking about the problem of installing the extension pack instead of asking how to manage without it. Please add to your post what happens when you try to install it.

Comment: I believe you cannot directly access usb2.0 device without extension pack.As a workaround, you can try usbip http://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2018/208/Tutorial-USB-IP

Comment: Please answer: What are your problems when installing the extension pack?

Comment: @harrymc Due to some redistribution issue we cannot install extension pack

Comment: @ilia I was not able to find windows server for USBIP,  So Iam trying to run an linux virtual box guest machine in parallel and add device in linux, in linux  we were  able to detect USB2.0 as USB 1.1. I succeded setting up USBIP server in linux .

Comment: @ilia Now Iam trying  USBIP client in windows guest machines and access USB, Not able to connect to the USBIP server . used Bridge network.

Comment: @harrymc Its source is not open.